# Using 'stack ghc', How do you compile a Haskell program with -fglasgow-exts?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I'm following Write Yourself Scheme in 48 Hours and I'm at the point in which the flag `-fglasgow-exts` must be used to compile to the program. I'm using a MacBook and Stack however when I try to run it with `stack ghc scheme.hs -fglasgow-exts` or `stack ghc -fglasgow-exts scheme.hs` I cannot get it to run. I tried using the command they used `ghc -package parsec -o scheme`, I get nothing as well.

Comment: Though not recommended (it is considered better style to turn on extensions individually), `-fglasgow-exts` [apparently still works on recent GHCs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=glasgow%20exts#ghc-flag--fglasgow-exts). Try using `stack ghc -- -fglasgow-exts scheme.hs`, to ensure the command line flag is passed to `ghc` rather than `stack`. If that doesn't work, you'll need to [edit] your question to add the error messages you are getting, so that we can see what is going on.

Comment: That compiled perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. In that case, I'll move the suggestion to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are using GHC through Stack, so if you want to pass command line flags such as `-fglasgow-exts` to GHC, you need to do it after a `--`, so that Stack doesn'r gobble up the flags:

```
stack ghc -- -fglasgow-exts scheme.hs
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow I haven't seen that flag on the command line for at least 5 years.  More idiomatic would be to put

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fglasgow-exts #-}
```

at the top of the file, but even that is quite antiquated.  The etiquette nowadays seems to be to enable extensions individually

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, RankNTypes #-}
```

Or whatever you need.  You can usually find out which extensions you need by leaving them out, and `ghc` will tell you in its error message.  If you don't know what one is, it's a nice opportunity to go read about it, which I personally find quite exciting.